# How to remove white border from right and down part instead having BorderStyle := bsNone in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have been trying making a border-less movable Inno Setup and figured how to make it movable and border-less but there are still border at the right and down part.

First my code was `BorderStyle := bsDialog`.

I changed to `BorderStyle := bsNone` to make the setup border-less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember a client size of the window before you change the `BorderStyle` and restore the client size afterwards:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  ClientWidth: Integer;
  ClientHeight: Integer;
begin
  ClientWidth := WizardForm.ClientWidth;
  ClientHeight := WizardForm.ClientHeight;

  WizardForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;

  WizardForm.ClientWidth := ClientWidth;
  WizardForm.ClientHeight := ClientHeight;
end;
```

[image: Borderless window]

Comment: Thnx very much martin but i have these line in my script there no problem with them i wanted to tell that as i change bsdialog to bsnone and compile i see no border on up and left but i get white extension on right and down part. I want a setup exactly like u have posted

Comment: How can i post a pic so that i could show u whats happening with me

Comment: The screenshot is for an installer built with the code in my answer. Did you try it (including the `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight` parts)?

Comment: Thnx very much man ; ur the best man i have ever met .really man hands off to u.great man thnx